# How to set up mySql JDBC connection with SSL

Tags: java, mysql, ssl

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDb?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true
```

I downloaded the public certificate from the mySql server and put it into cacerts like this:

```
keytool.exe -import -alias mysql_dev \
    -keystore /c/dev/tools/Java/jre1.8.0_131/jre/lib/security/cacerts \
    -file rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

I generated new keys using `keytool` like this:

```
keytool.exe -genkeypair -alias adam \
               -keypass changeit \
               -keysize 1024 \
               -keystore /c/dev/.secure/haa2xt.jks \
               -storepass changeit
```

So now I can see that Java is picking up both my key from the keystore and the server certificate from the truststore, but still I'm getting the `PKIX` error.

> PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I added this debug param to the command line and got some more info which all looks good, and I can see the mySql certificate in there.

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

> trustStore is: c:\dev\tools\java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\security\cacerts
>
> trustStore type is : jks

[.....]

> keyStore is : C:/dev/.secure/haa2xt.jks
>
> keyStore type is : jks
>
> keyStore provider is :
>
> init keystore
>
> init keymanager of type SunX509
>
> *** found key for : adam

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `keytool import` command will only import the first certificate in the PEM file when there are more than one.

This was the only one I checked for as well, so I thought it was fine when actually there were about 15 that I still hadn't imported.

I used this tool to import them all: https://github.com/use-sparingly/keyutil